# Why I cannot run a tensor and got error "the variable was uninitialized"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, initialization, tensor

I'm using tensorflow 1.15.0.

I'm trying to get a keras layer output value with sess.run(). And I'm sure I have specified layer input shape and I could see a output tensor with the right shape. But when I tried to get tensor value, there are errors.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

sess = tf.Session()
layer = layers.Dense(3)
x = tf.ones((1, 4))
y = layer(x)
layer.weights # I want to get weights value, print it first
```

The result is as expected:

> [<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(4, 3) dtype=float32>,
> <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>]

But when I tried to get tensor value:

```
sess.run(layer.weights[0])
```

A very long error message pops: (the following is the core message)

> FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense/kernel)

Could someone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you need to initialize variables (in the dense layer) before you use them e.g with [tf.global_variables_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/global_variables). Try adding the following line after declaring the variables but before using them:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

You can also call [tf.variables_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/variables) to initialize variables from a list.